# How do I create a simplified logic circuit of this given [(A’B’)’ + (A’+ B’)’]’ ? and What is the simplified Boolean expression?

Tags: boolean, logic, boolean-expression, boolean-algebra

I have to draw the simplified logic circuit of this given  [(A’B’)’ + (A’+ B’)’]’ and also get the simplified boolean expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From DeMorgan Theory

```
     ((A'B')' + (A'+ B')')'=(A+B + AB)'   
     (A+B + AB)'   = (A+B)'. (AB)'
     (A+B)'. (AB)' = (A'.B') .(A'+B')
```

**assume**

```
X=A' ,Y=B'
```

we can conclude that

```
(XY)(X+Y) is (XY)
```

as both (XY) and (X+Y) has to be 1 to produce 1 at output as seen from truth table of (XY)(X+Y) is (XY) is identical to XY

[image]

so as final result

```
((A'B')' + (A'+ B')')'=(A+B + AB)'  

(A+B + AB)'   = (A+B)'. (AB)'

(A+B)'. (AB)' = (A'.B') .(A'+B') = A'B'
```

before simplifying

[image]

after simplifying

[image]

comparing outputs to make sure

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> (A'B')' = A + B

Using DeMorgan's theorem (AB)' = A' + B'

> (A'+B')' = AB

Again, using DeMorgan's theorem (A+B)' = A'B'

Therefore, now we have the expression:

> (A+B + AB)'

Taking A+B as X and AB as Y

> (X+Y)' = X'Y'
> = (A+B)'·(AB)'

Now, creating a logic circuit is fairly simple for this expression, inputs A and B are fed to a NOR gate and NAND gate simultaneously whose outputs act as input to an AND gate

[image: Preview]

Comment: how about this?  (A’B )’ + A’ B’)’ + A'

Comment: Firstly, there's a missing parenthesis and secondly, what are you trying to achieve? This is a place for asking help if you are stuck somewhere with a problem; but not getting solutions for your hw. In case you were struggling to get started, I gave you an example. Now what did you try? Where did that get you? Where are you facing an issue?